# Calling simple java static method via JNI does not work, though c++ compiles and run it

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

Considering this Java class with the static method:

```
public class TestClass{
    public string str;
    public TestClass() {
        str = "Test From Java";
    }
    public static String staticMethod() {
        return "Test From Java";
    }
}
```

I have written these lines of code in c++ file:

```
QAndroidJniObject str =  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
                                   "org/.../TestClass"
                                   ,"staticMethod"
                                   ,"(V)Ljava/lang/String;");
```

It seems everything is working but I don't know how can I use the `str` Object. I tried to convert it to a `QString` object using `str.tostring()` method but it always returns an empty string.
Why it does not work as expected? I've also tested `()Ljava/lang/String;` for method signature but no success!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the returned JNI type in `<...>` when calling the method :

```
QAndroidJniObject str =  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>(
                               "org/.../TestClass"
                               ,"staticMethod");

QString string = str.toString();
```

Here there is no need to define the signature since your function has no argument.

Comment: Thank you Nejat. It worked successfully. But what about a static method which return type is string and has some input parameters? I tried use callStaticObjectMethod but there is no matching function:  `QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>("org/.../TestClass"
                                                       ,"staticMethod"
                                                       ,"(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"
                                                       ,val.object<jstring>());`

Comment: val is a QAndroidJniObject: `QAndroidJniObject::fromString("This is test");`

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your approach, i can't think of anything. May be it's better to ask this problem in a new question and describe it more.