# Qt does not compile callStaticObjectMethod()

Tags: c++, qt, java-native-interface, qtandroidextras

I wrote the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693031/calling-simple-java-static-method-via-jni-does-not-work-though-c-compiles-and) and it was compiled and worked perfectly:

```
QAndroidJniObject str =  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>(
                               "org/.../TestClass"
                               ,"staticMethod");
```

Now I have changed the java method and it needs an input parameter of type string.

**The Java code**:

```
public class TestClass{
    public string str;
    public TestClass() {
        str = "Test From Java";
    }
    public static String staticMethod(String str) {
        return "Test From Java, "+str;
    }
}
```

But adding the method signature and input parameter does not work for me. I wrote this code to invoke the static method within the mentioned java class using JNI:

```
QAndroidJniObject val = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("Test String");
QAndroidJniObject str = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod<jstring>(
          "org/.../TestClass"
          ,"staticMethod"
          ,"(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"
          ,val.object<jstring>());
```

But Qt creator does not build it, printing this error:

> ```
> ...testclass.cpp:21: error:
> no matching function for call to 'QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
> const char [36], const char [13], const char [39], _jstring*)'
>                                                         ,val.object<jstring>());
>                                                                               ^
> ```

Thanks for any help.

### I also tried callStaticMethod

For this:

```
jstring str = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jstring>(
                      "org/.../TestClass"
                      ,"staticMethod"
                      ,"(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"
                      ,val.object<jstring>());
```

I got the following error :

> ...\testclass.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to '_jstring* QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<_jstring*>(char const*, char
>   const*, char const*, ...)'

## I also tried callStaticObjectMethod without template parameter ##

> QAndroidJniObject str = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/...TextClass" ,"staticMethod" ,"(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;",val.object());

*It always returns an empty string. I'm not sure if it is really emty or not. I use `qCritical() << str.toString();` to print the string but an empty qout is printed then!*

Comment: Is `callStaticObjectMethod<jstring` a typo?

Comment: @Nejat Yes, I updated it.

Comment: Try to use `callStaticObjectMethod` without `<jstring>` and see if you can read the string from the returned value using `str.toString()`.

Comment: @Nejat It returns "", an empty string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
QAndroidJniObject str = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
          "org/.../TestClass"
          ,"staticMethod"
          ,"(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"
          ,val.object<jstring>());
```

I think this function doesn't take template parameter.

Than you can do:

```
str.toString() //returns QString
```

---

And make sure you have imported the Java source files to your android build. For example if your java classes are under `android-sources` folder add this to your .pro file:

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-sources
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it. It returns an empty string nothing else :(

Comment: @a.toraby what should it return ? I never ran into any problems with this method

Comment: Hi there. I've updated the question and added the java class. It's simply supposed to concatenate the input string to another one. I would appreciate it if you take a look at it.

Comment: I say it returns empty according to the `qCritical() << str.toString();` May be problem is the toString() method that cant convert jstring to Qstring?