# what are the usage of callStaticObjectMethod callStaticMethod

Tags: qt, qtandroidextras, qandroidjniobject

The qt documentation is poor in QAndroidJniObject object. Could you possibly tell me what the difference between `callStaticObjectMethod` and `callStaticMethod` is and when should I use them?
If you have any working example, It would be appreciated if address them in you answers. (like Q notifier)
Thank you

Comment: `callStaticMethod`  is used for basic types like int, float and `callStaticObjectMethod` for more complex objects like string

Comment: @prajmus Thanks. Have you ever used callStaticObjectMethod yet? Should I use it when return type and input arguments are String? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695794/qt-does-not-compile-callstaticobjectmethod-it-says-no-matching-function-to-cal) I tried to use it in order to call a java static method but I failed to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in a comment, the `callStaticMethod` is used with primitive types (which are listed [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#primitive-types)). This function returns the type you requested (ex. `jint`) not `QAndroidJniObject`.

And `callStaticObjectMethod` is used with methods returning an object type (which are listed [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#primitive-types)). It returns the `QAndroidJniObject`.

You can find example code in *Qt* unit test files on their [git repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtandroidextras/source/c1d9cc68c7a70fe3a61a0b21b57bf4afd990e564:tests/auto/qandroidjniobject/tst_qandroidjniobject.cpp)